# Card Sorting - Huge Company

Tags: usability, menu, organization, card-sorting

We're going to redesign the company's website that I work on but I have a lot of menus and different services to organize

We offer all these kind of services:

**Education**
Short-Term Courses, Certificate Programs, University, Distance Learning

**For Companies**
In-Company Training, Product Development, Research, Workshops, Financing, etc

We also have a TV program and a publishing company.

For each of these things we have many technical areas like: chemistry, mechanics, Construction and Building Technology, Manufacturing and Engineering, Information and Communication, etc.
Spread over 90 unities across the state

I dont now how can I create cards for my Card Sorting Session, because I can be very specific like "Basic Excel Training" Or not like "Software Development Courses"

How can I decide what level of cards Im going to use? And What granularity could I use?

Answer (score 1):

You have a complex scenario for sure, but remember you don't need to have a card for each and every item. As a matter of fact, according to [**Card Sorting**](https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/card-sorting.html) at usability.gov:

> Create your list of content topics. Topics can be phrases or words,
>   very specific or more general. As a suggestion, limit yourself to
>   50-60 topics or less. This means there might not be a card to sort for
>   every page on the site.
>
> - For a new site, list the content topics of types of information that you are likely to have on the site
> - For an existing site, list the most important / popular types of content
> - To create this list:
>
>   - Review the content listed in your content inventory.
>   - Identify the most important or most frequently used content

So, granularity will be defined by you, but you won't need every course, or every micro-page, just the most important branches in your trees. For example:

```
Home --> Taxonomy1 --> Taxonomy2 --> Any Item
```

where taxonomies are identified, but "Any item" is literally "any item" (for example, each specific course).

## Additionally

When building a hierarchy tree for your scenario, you'll have a *hub/umbrella*, and several business areas. You can treat each business area on a *one by one* basis, and **perform card sorting tests on each of these business areas**. Then you go *up the tree* and **perform a secondary card sorting instance for each business area**. So, using the same example above:

```
Hub --> Site Home --> Taxonomy1 --> Taxonomy2 --> Any Item
```